# Alloy model without GUI

Tags: python, model, logic, alloy, formal-methods

I want to write a scalable program in Python that would create Alloy models depending on the user input. In particular, I want user to input a graph and use Alloy to tell the user whether the graph has an Eulerian path. I have the model ready in Alloy for a particular instance of graph. However, I am thinking of generating .als file via Python code and then fire up Alloy through Python to evaluate the model. Is there an Alloy API I can use or any command line arguments that can help me decide whether a certain predicate is consistent or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine asked me the same question few days ago.

I developed a small Java program based on the Alloy API that takes a path to a given Alloy module as input, analyses the input module (taking into consideration the first command encountered), and display (as output) if the analyzer found a satisfiable instance for the given module and command.

Here is a link to this very simple program.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ekwegj0ltfs8lq/alloy_text-based.jar?dl=0

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no Alloy API for Python.  The [official API is in Java](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/alloy-api/index.html); examples of the API usage can be found [here](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation.html) (as well as  here on StackOverflow).  There is also an [embedding of Alloy in Ruby](http://people.csail.mit.edu/aleks/website/arby/), which is still in alpha.